# Nilradical of $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^nY^m)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm having trouble finding the nilradical of $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^nY^m)$ for given $n$ and $m$. I believe the nilradical is $\{f(XY) \in \mathbb{R}[XY] : f \textrm{ has constant term 0}\}/(X^nY^m)\}$. It's easy enough to see that thse polynomials are nilpotent (due to the lack of constant term, you take $xy$ out of the polynomial, so taking the third power is enough), but I'm having trouble proving that any other element in $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^nY^m)$ is not nilpotent.

My idea is that all other polynomials will have either a constant term, or a term in only $x$ (or a power of $x$), or a term in only $y$ (or a power of $y$). Then any power of this polynomial will still give such term, and thus it cannot equal $0$. Is this reasoning correct and sufficient?

Comment: $XY^2$ is no in the nilradical? Note, what you have defined is not an ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the problem conceptually simpler, note that the nilradical of $R/I$ is the image of the radical of $I$ under the projection $\pi: R\rightarrow R/I$, since $(f+I)^{k}=0+I$ iff $f^{k}\in I$.

Now, assuming $n,m\geq 1$, one can calculate the radical of $I=(X^{n}Y^{m})$ in $R$ to be $\sqrt{I}=(XY)$.

To show one inclusion: without loss of generality, $n\geq m$. Then for any $f\in(XY),$ $f^{n}$ is divisible by $X^{n}Y^{n}$, which is divisible by $X^{n}Y^{m}$ since $n\geq m$. Thus $f^{n}\in I$, so $f\in\sqrt{I}$ by definition of radical. We conclude $(XY)\subseteq\sqrt{I}$.

On the other hand, if $f\notin(XY)$, then f has either a term $X^{i}$ for some $i\geq 0$, or a term $Y^{j}$ for some $j\geq 0$. Then for any $l\geq 0$, $f^{l}$ will have either a term $X^{il}$ or a term $Y^{jl}$, neither of which is divisible by $X^{n}Y^{m}$. Thus f cannot be in $\sqrt{I}$. We conclude that $X\supseteq\sqrt{I}$.

Hence we must have $\sqrt{I}=(XY)$, so the desired nilradical is the ideal generated by $XY+(X^{n}Y^{m})$.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume $n,m\geq 1$; if one of them is $0$ you will get a different answer.

$\{f(XY)\}$, what you have written down, is not an ideal, but it does *generate* the nilradical.  For an ideal $I$, to check $I\subset \sqrt{0}$ you can just check that the generators are nilpotent.  To check $\sqrt{0}$, one possibility is to compute $A/I$ (where $A=\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^n Y^m)$).

An alternative strategy would be to find all the prime ideals of $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ which contain $X^n Y^m$, and find their intersection.